# HTTP POST fails because of double dash (hyphen) in parameter value

Tags: http

I've found this problem when I was doing some stuff for a customer. 
Whenever some form was posted (using ajax) the server was responding with a 404 but this was only happening whenever the data contained a parameter with double dashes in the value of it.
I dont have full access to the server but all I found in the error log was "/var/www/digital/sites/ftp/htdocs/favicon.ico" File does not exist. I can only imagine that something is going wrong in the HTACCESS or something. Anyone has an idea?

Some example:

```
var d = "Friday|~|&lt;#if contact.edm_mailpack?starts_with(\"Val\")&gt; ${\"${contact.soort_aanvraag!}\"?uncap_first}&lt;#if contact.merk?has_content &amp;&amp; contact.model_1?has_content&gt; van de ${contact.merk_1!} ${contact.model_1!}&lt;#elseif contact.edm_mailpack?starts_with(\"UC\")&gt;Kucsdcailpack?starts_with(\"CC\")&gt;Bescdds geÃ¯nteressseerd&lt;#if contact.merk?has_content &amp;&amp; contact.model_1?has_content&gt; in de ${contact.merk_1!} ${contact.model_1!}<!--#if-->?<!--#if-->|~|some other data";
var d2 = d.replace(/--/g, '');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://xxxxx/dt_csv_export.php',
        //contentType: 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8',
        data: {
            action: "generate",
            csv_type: oTable.attr('id'),
            csv_data: d2
        },
        success: function(download_link) {
            location.href = download_link;
        }
    }).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        alert(textStatus); 
    });
```

Comment: A lame SQL-injection protection? -- means a comment in SQL.

Comment: _"I dont have full access to the server [...] I can only imagine"_ - so can we. This cannot be answered.

Comment: Thats why I put the question here :) Anyway the probabable cause is the url rewrite engine on this server, I guess, while no RFC writes about this.